# Eclipse Marketplace slow, how to speed it up?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I consistently get very slow downloads with Eclipse Marketplace (right now 25 kB/s over a 3 MB/s line from http://download.eclipse.org), which make it very tedious to use with Eclipse 3.7 SR 1.   "Eclipse marketplace slow" give a lot of false positives when searching.

Is there a trick to speed up the process?

(I just need the egit and m2e-wtp plugins).

Comment: got the same problem, it runs fast on my laptop and extremely slow on my desktop on the same network during initialization of the marketplace screen while retrieving the listings, or installing something :-/

Comment: For what it is worth I got a new job where we use IntelliJ and that completely fixed the problem for me :)  A brief detour back in Eclipse recently showed that the problem was still there :-/

Answer (score 3):

You can download the p2 update-sites via your browser, add a local p2 repository pointing to the extracted repository and install them from your local harddrive.
for egit: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/
but I dont' know if m2e-wtp is available via repository for download.

The advantages (which can have an impact to the speed of that process):

1. You can choose a mirror when downloading from eclipse.org
2. You don't have all the xml-overhead from the marketplace-client.

There is also something called "[Friends for eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/donate/)" where you get more bandwidth if you donate at least 35$

Answer (score 1):

[MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com) has high bandwith update mirrors. You could also set up a caching proxy.

Answer (score 0):

My Juno eclipse seems to occasionally hang initializing DND marketplace (Seems to be after adding GAE plugin, but that is supposition).

A workround is to rename the project directories that you are working on. Start eclipse. Then change them back again.

Not entirely an answer to the question asked, but thought I would share anyway.